# Livepatch announcements - what they mean?

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now all OK except this: what does it mean in practice, when Livepatch informs that: ''No updates currently applied.''? Does it mean that updates have been downloaded from Canonical to my PC, but they are not installed ? Or does it mean something else ? What should I do in practice with these kind of Livepatch announcements ? In case these announcements do not mean anything could you please stop sending them ?